# What's the meaning of CHECK_FOR_FORK?

Tags: ios, core-foundation

I am reading the source code of Core Foundation. I see lots of code with `CHECK_FOR_FORK`. I don't know what does this mean and what is the use of it, can anyone help me?

Here is an example snippet:

```
#if DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_MACOSX || DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_EMBEDDED || DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_EMBEDDED_MINI
extern uint8_t __CF120293;
extern uint8_t __CF120290;
extern void __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__(void);
#define CHECK_FOR_FORK() do { __CF120290 = true; if (__CF120293) __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__(); } while (0)
#define CHECK_FOR_FORK_RET(...) do { CHECK_FOR_FORK(); if (__CF120293) return __VA_ARGS__; } while (0)
#define HAS_FORKED() (__CF120293)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Forking is a system call where a process creates a copy of itself. `CHECK_FOR_FORK` is a boolean value in the code which checks whether the given process was forked.

Read more about forking on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)).